# Java - 2d Array not filling when transferring info from file

Tags: java, arrays, io

In my program I am trying to read a file that contains Strings, booleans and doubles. I'm trying to have it skip a line if it determines that it isn't a double when filling an array. This is done by first checking if there is data on the line. Then it determines if the first character is a number or not. However, when I print the supposedly filled array with Arrays.deepToString it shows this:

```
[[2.33, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], ...
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why it isn't filling properly. Here is the sample code:

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    double data[][] = new double[30][6];
    int indexRow = 0, indexCol = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String temp = input.nextLine();

        if(temp.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0)))
            {
                data[indexRow][indexCol] = input.nextDouble();

                if(indexCol < 6) indexCol++;
                if(indexRow < 30 && indexCol % 6 == 0)
                {
                    indexRow++;
                    indexCol = 0;
                }
            }
            else{}
        }   
        else
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

    return data;
}
```

Here is a sample of the file (it should just fill the array with the doubles):

```
Washington Capitals
3.02
2.33
85.2
30.6
28.4
True
Dallas Stars
3.23
2.78
82.3
32.0
28.9
True
St. Louis Blues
2.67
2.40
85.1
30.2
29.7
True
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the current array:

```
[[3.02, 2.33, 85.2, 30.6, 28.4], [3.23, 2.78, 82.3, 32.0, 28.9], [2.67, 2.4, 85.1, 30.2, 29.7], [2.94, 2.43, 84.4, 33.2, 29.7], [2.83, 2.44, 79.5, 28.8, 29.5], [2.85, 2.52, 80.3, 30.5, 30.8], [2.62, 2.29, 87.2, 30.3, 27.5], [2.72, 2.34, 81.4, 32.0, 27.5], [2.84, 2.62, 78.2, 28.5, 30.4], [2.77, 2.57, 84.5, 29.4, 30.4], [2.89, 2.52, 80.5, 30.4, 27.4], [2.73, 2.41, 84.0, 29.3, 28.9], [2.73, 2.6, 81.2, 30.6, 27.3], [2.57, 2.56, 80.5, 31.0, 30.7], [2.88, 2.78, 82.2, 32.0, 30.4], [2.55, 2.67, 81.5, 29.7, 29.7], [2.6, 2.49, 77.9, 29.0, 28.6], [2.39, 2.7, 84.3, 29.9, 27.6], [2.8, 2.94, 75.8, 28.4, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Here is the full file:

```
Carolina Hurricanes
2.39
2.70
84.3
29.9
27.6
False
Ottawa Senators
2.80
2.94
75.8
28.4
32.8
False
New Jersey Devils
2.22
2.46
83.0
24.4
28.6
False
Colorado Avalanche
2.59
2.93
80.2
28.6
32.3
False
Montréal Canadiens
2.63
2.84
81.9
30.5
29.4
False
Buffalo Sabres
2.43
2.62
82.6
29.5
30.6
False
Winnipeg Jets
2.59
2.88
78.4
29.6
29.5
False
Arizona Coyotes
2.54
2.98
77.3
27.6
31.0
False
Calgary Flames
2.79
3.13
75.5
29.2
29.0
False
Columbus Blue Jackets
2.60
3.02
81.0
29.1
31.1
False
Vancouver Canucks
2.27
2.91
81.1
28.2
32.5
False
Edmonton Oilers
2.43
2.95
81.1
29.1
31.1
False
Toronto Maple Leafs
2.34
2.93
81.6
30.7
30.5
False
```

Comment: per iteration you already read the line here `String temp = input.nextLine();` and then try to parse that line here `data[indexRow][indexCol] = input.nextDouble();`, but what this does is reading another line...you want to use `data[indexRow][indexCol] = Double.parseDouble(temp);` as it parses the previously checked line

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret thanks for the input.

Comment: is your problem solved? if not I'll create a more detailed answer with another small issue and elaborite it further, also thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret Actually, it only partially filled the array. It left about 11 of the 30 sets at the end blank. The last set that was filled was only half filled as well.

Comment: for me it works perfectly with the sample data, although you have only 5 doubles each iteration instead of 6 like the array length suggests

Comment: is it possible that you have an empty line in your file? because the `else break;` in your code would stop whenever you encounter an empty line - it should be `else continue;` if you just want to skip those lines

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I changed all of the 6's to 5's and all it did was fill one more of the last set that was filled. I'll edit the question to show what the current array holds. And no, no line breaks.

Comment: I made another comment, can you try that also? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I changed all of the 6's

Comment: no i mean my comment with the break and continue ; when I'm home I'll paste a complete solution, if these comments aren't that clear

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I tried what you said and it made it so that the array did not fill at all. I switched the continue and the break and it did not fix my problem.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted some comments, so I added my code as an answer with my output. even if I add empty lines it works

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret Could it be that the file is to large to transfer? If so, how would you get around that problem. Also, I added the full file above.

Comment: i doubt that that is the case, but if it is I pasted another way of implementing the readFile method - that one uses a BufferedReader, which will only read line after line

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret Thanks for the suggestion. I'll get back to you by tonight (12:00 EST here) with my findings. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret Thank you for all of your help. After some searching and experimentation, it seems that the problem was that Notepad was encoding in ANSI and Netbeans in UTF-8. I downloaded Notepad++, copied my data into a .txt that encoded UTF-8 and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code worked perfectly for me with *your* sample input

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    double data[][] = new double[30][6];
    int indexRow = 0, indexCol = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String temp = input.nextLine();

            if (temp.trim().length() == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                if (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))) {
                    data[indexRow][indexCol] = Double.parseDouble(temp);

                    if (indexCol < 6)
                        indexCol++;
                    if (indexRow < 30 && indexCol % 6 == 0) {
                        indexRow++;
                        indexCol = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

    return data;
}
```

this is how I tested it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double[][] result = readFile("array.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < result[i].length; k++) {
            if (isFirst)
                isFirst = false;
            else
                System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.printf("%5s", result[i][k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and here's the output

```
[[3.02, 2.33, 85.2, 30.6, 28.4, 3.23], [2.78, 82.3, 32.0, 28.9, 2.67, 2.4], [85.1, 30.2, 29.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
 3.02,  2.33,  85.2,  30.6,  28.4,  3.23
 2.78,  82.3,  32.0,  28.9,  2.67,   2.4
 85.1,  30.2,  29.7,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
  0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0
```

my function readFile implemented with a BufferedReader

```
public static double[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    double data[][] = new double[30][6];
    int indexRow = 0, indexCol = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String temp = input.readLine();
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))) {
                    data[indexRow][indexCol] = Double.parseDouble(temp);

                    if (indexCol < 6)
                        indexCol++;
                    if (indexRow < 30 && indexCol % 6 == 0) {
                        indexRow++;
                        indexCol = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            }

            temp = input.readLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

    return data;
}
```